# Как изменить иконку у определнной метки?

Tags: yandexmapkit

Не получается выбрать определнную метку из тех что были проставлены ранее, хотелось бы после выбора определенного объекта в списке recyclerView не только перемещаться к его месту нахождения, но и изменять иконку.

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать дынный способ для смены иконки в Yandex MapKit. Но вам необходимо иметь ссылку на маркер, иконку которого вы хотите заменить.

```
private fun editMarker(mapObject: PlacemarkMapObject?, @DrawableRes imageRes: Int) {
    mapObject?.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(context, imageRes))
}
```

При добавлении маркера на карту методом mapObjectCollection.addPlacemark() вы получаете ссылку на маркер. Можете ее сохранить для последующего изменения.